# accessibility for empty table cells

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accessibility

We are using axe to test accessibility.

Axe is giving the following issue when table cells are empty:

> All th element and elements with role=columnheader/rowheader must data cells which it describes

If we do this for empty table cells:

```
<td><span style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }}>empty</span>
```

The problem goes away but this is a bit hacky. Anyone know the best fix for this?

Worth knowing that this DOES NOT fix the problem:

```
<td><span style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }}>&nbsp;</span>
```

We are working in a React environment hence the React style markup.

Comment: Although I wouldn't usually advise writing "hacky" solutions just to allow HTML to pass validation (because that's often at the expense of a lesser user experience), your first solution might actually be the better. However, rather than "empty" I'd go with something more descriptive, such as "not applicable" or "not available" (whichever is the case). That's likely to be more useful to someone using a screen reader than simply an empty cell which doesn't indicate if the data is intentionally not present.

Comment: I think the warning by Axe is a bit silly. In its purest form, a table is a representation of a table in a database, where fields can be empty. I mean, an empty value for a field in a database record is perfectly valid, so why would you need tricks to make sure <td> elements are not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There's nothing like this restriction in the WCAG.**

A data cell can be empty. `td` elements have the `cell` role and [this role does not require an accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#cell).

According to [axe unit tests](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/blob/1fb227860decba4a56492c0fe22de4c2cec25bc5/test/checks/tables/th-has-data-cells.js), this error only shows when there's no non-empty `td` associated with the `th`. You should have two solution : replacing the `th` with a `td` or adding an accessible name (using for instance the `aria-label="No value"` attribute for instance)

Comment: Just a note here that the aria-label solution you mention is specifically called out as an incorrect solution in the axe docs: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.5/empty-table-header

Comment: @Pixelpush3r You misread my answer and the problem here. The problem here is having only empty `td` associated with a non empty `th`. Obviously an empty `th` makes no sense